# Make the parent div width the same as the children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I made this layout that seems to work, the only problem is that I would like that all che filled div are centered.

There are three possible "states":

1. the cyan element is to the left of all the others
2. the gold and pink elements are on two columns
3. all elements are on a single column.

What I want:
[image: state1]
[image: state2]
[image: state3]

In the first case, everything is centered and it works, in the other two it doesn't: the elements are always aligned to the left.

To center I was thinking of using `margin: 0 auto` but it seems the divs are bigger than their content even if [I used `inline-flex`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezcV6.png) (look at the grey area during state #3 in the running example). Why?

How can I solve?

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 490px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.columns {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.map {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.content {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.cards {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  background-color: pink;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.card.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.texts {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.text {
  background-color: gold;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="map"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card left">card #1</div>
        <div class="card">card #2</div>
        <div class="card left">card #3</div>
        <div class="card">card #4</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="texts">
        <div class="text left">text #1</div>
        <div class="text">text #2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you already considred the use of a CSS Grid? To me it seems as a better and easier solution overall.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want. This? https://jsfiddle.net/ghL8qb71/

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thank you Michael but your example doesn't work as I want. I added  3 images with the result I expected.

Comment: @tacoshy thank you for the tip, have you some example to show me something similar to what I would like to have? I added 3 images in the main message

Comment: are you okay to change the HTML structure or the current one is needed?

Comment: @AtulRajput I'm ok to change the HTML structure

Comment: one more quick question, the way you assigned width to the items, like 150px, 320px. is it mandatory, as this is not the problem but not a good approach, posting a solution with the current CSS in a while

Comment: @AtulRajput I know it's not a nice approach but the size of some elements is fixed: the cyan element has a fixed width and height, the same for the pink and gold elements

Comment: in this case, you can achieve what you want very easily with a media query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use media queries in the proper way and here you go, to play with it find [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkud3oax/) link, try to resize the result window.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 490px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.columns {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.map {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.cards {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.texts {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  background-color: gold;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
@media(max-width: 520px){
.container {

    display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
 .columns {
    display: inline-block;
    
  }
}
@media(max-width: 352px){
.container {

    display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
  .map {margin-right: 0;}
 
  .content {
        max-width: min-content;
  }
.card.left {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.text.left {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="map"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card left">card #1</div>
        <div class="card">card #2</div>
        <div class="card left">card #3</div>
        <div class="card">card #4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="texts">
        <div class="text left">text #1</div>
        <div class="text">text #2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems not to work properly. During state #2, content is not centered (https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/44204353/97284070-e2fae880-1840-11eb-878c-65d15d223622.gif)

Comment: changed the code as per your need and updated the fidlle link too